# Not getting contact items from outlook 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook

I am developing a WPF-C# application and fetching MS Outlook 2010 contact items using Redemption. It is working fine if my Outlook has only one SMTP account. But if I configure another account which is exchange server account then I don't get any contact item from the same code. Following is my code:

```
        Interop.Redemption.RDOItems folderItems = null;
        Interop.Redemption.RDOFolder folderContacts = null;
        Interop.Redemption.RDOFolder folderSuggestedContacts = null;
        List<GMContactItem> allOutlookContacts = null;
        object itemObj = null;
        List<Interop.Redemption.RDOContactItem> contactItemsList = null;

        try
        {

            folderContacts = (RDOFolder)RDOSessionItem.GetDefaultFolder(Interop.Redemption.rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
            contactItemsList = new List<RDOContactItem>();
            folderItems = folderContacts.Items;
            for (int i = 1; folderItems.Count >= i; i++)
            {
                itemObj = folderItems[i];
                if (itemObj is Interop.Redemption.RDOContactItem)
                    contactItemsList.Add(itemObj as RDOContactItem);
                else
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itemObj);
            }

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(folderItems);
            folderItems = null;


            // getting items from the Suggested Contacts folder in Outlook 
            folderSuggestedContacts = RDOSessionItem.GetDefaultFolder(
                                      rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderSuggestedContacts);
            if (folderSuggestedContacts != null)
            {
                folderItems = folderSuggestedContacts.Items;
                for (int i = 1; folderItems.Count >= i; i++)
                {
                    itemObj = folderItems[i];
                    if (itemObj is Interop.Redemption.RDOContactItem)
                        contactItemsList.Add(itemObj as Interop.Redemption.RDOContactItem);
                    else
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(itemObj);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

When I delete my exchange server account then it work fine and if I add exchange server account in Outlook then this code has no exception but don't give any contact item. Can anybody suggest me that what could be the issue here. Thanks in advance.

-Surya

Comment: Does the Contacts folder in the Exchange mailbox include any items?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, basically I am working with two accounts one is SMPT and other is exchange server. Yes there are contacts in my exchange mailbox because when I open select name dialog, it contains many contacts. Apart from this, second account which is SMTP account, this has many contacts in address book as well. Also, if I run the same application with outlook 2007 then it is working good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at the GAL entries? These address entries exist in GAL (AD based), not in the Contacts folder of the Exchange mailbox.

If you need to open the Contacts folder of the (non-default) PST store, call RDOStore.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) instead of RDOSession.GetDefaultFolder (which returns a folder from the default store).

The secondary PST store can be opened using the RDOSession.Stores collection.